# JQuery - Including JQuery causes alert not to run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run the code given below (which I've simplified to pin point the problem). When I exclude the `src` part for the script (i.e. leave out the source of the JQuery) then the alert will run fine, but results in the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'offset'`. This is due to JQuery not being included. However, when I add the `src` part in (as seen below), I get no errors or warnings, but the code doesn't run as far as I can tell. Specifically, there is no alert (or anything else). I'm guessing I'm just making some silly mistake on how to include JQuery, but I'm not sure what it is. Any suggestions? Thank you much!

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" >      
  getPosition = function() {
    var the_source = document.getElementById('the_source');
    var offset = the_source.offset();
    var x_position = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var y_position = e.clientY - offset.top;
    alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
    alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
  }

  initialize = function() {
    alert('check');
    getPosition();
  }      

  setTimeout(initialize, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have both a "src" attribute and in-line script code in a single `<script>` block.  Import jQuery with its own `<script>` block (with no in-line content), and then put your script in another one.

Unless you're coding with a strict DOCTYPE, you don't need the "type" attribute either.

*edit* — also, you're importing jQuery (or trying to) but not using it properly:

```
var the_source = document.getElementById('the_source');
```

The call to "getElementById" remains a plain old DOM API call after importing jQuery.  If you want to use jQuery APIs, you have to make a jQuery object:

```
var the_source = $('#the_source');
```

Comment: So trying this, with a format similar to Karl Anderson's answer, I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'offset'`. Any ideas why?

Comment: @golmschenk yes, it's because you're not making a jQuery object. I'll extend the answer.

Comment: Great, that fixes it. Will accept the answer once I'm allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The `src` attribute is only for script references, not script blocks, you need this instead:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Your script here
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to seperate out the jquery and your own code.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script>    
          getPosition = function() {
            var the_source = document.getElementById('the_source');
            var offset = the_source.offset();
            var x_position = e.clientX - offset.left;
            var y_position = e.clientY - offset.top;
            alert(e.clientX - offset.left);
            alert(e.clientY - offset.top);
          }

          initialize = function() {
            alert('check');
            getPosition();
          }      

          setTimeout(initialize, 100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jQuery in its own `script` tag.

For the inline script please use a separate `script` tag